# Solr: Do documents get scored if the sort parameter is specified?

Tags: performance, solr

We have tons of what are functionally filter queries shoved into the main query (q parameter). I'm concerned that these extra pieces are getting scored unnecessarily. However we do specify a sort, and the score is not included in the sort. So my question is whether or not the search gets scored since ultimately it is not sorted by score?

Comment: So you ask, if those filter querys get scored or not? Or are you also concerned about the main query? Or in general? It is a bit vague.

Answer (score 0):

Based on "explain" logs, looks like it scores even when you specify sort param on a field.

Here is the "explain" log i observed for query without sort param, (results were ordered by score):

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/logmill/select?q=text_en%3A%22not+found%22&wt=xml&indent=true&debugQuery=true


<lst name="explain">
<str name="localhost/281/info/1373983754934/5ba362b4e8a6fce36ba650cf8e946771">
2.2986562 = (MATCH) weight(text_en:found in 131) [DefaultSimilarity], result of: 2.2986562 = fieldWeight in 131, product of: 1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of: 1.0 = termFreq=1.0 4.5973125 = idf(docFreq=3, maxDocs=146) 0.5 = fieldNorm(doc=131)
</str>
<str name="localhost/258/info/1373983752897/8a2e39f484dedff91bd11b94f442bd8a">
1.7239921 = (MATCH) weight(text_en:found in 126) [DefaultSimilarity], result of: 1.7239921 = fieldWeight in 126, product of: 1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of: 1.0 = termFreq=1.0 4.5973125 = idf(docFreq=3, maxDocs=146) 0.375 = fieldNorm(doc=126)
</str>
<str name="localhost/294/info/1373983755710/8a2e39f484dedff91bd11b94f442bd8a">
1.7239921 = (MATCH) weight(text_en:found in 136) [DefaultSimilarity], result of: 1.7239921 = fieldWeight in 136, product of: 1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of: 1.0 = termFreq=1.0 4.5973125 = idf(docFreq=3, maxDocs=146) 0.375 = fieldNorm(doc=136)
</str>
</lst>
</lst>
```

Following is "explain" logs for query with sort param,  (results were ordered by timestamp_tdt field):

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/logmill/select?q=text_en%3A%22not+found%22&wt=xml&indent=true&debugQuery=true&sort=timestamp_tdt%20asc

<lst name="explain">
<str name="localhost/258/info/1373983752897/8a2e39f484dedff91bd11b94f442bd8a">
1.7239921 = (MATCH) weight(text_en:found in 126) [DefaultSimilarity], result of: 1.7239921 = fieldWeight in 126, product of: 1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of: 1.0 = termFreq=1.0 4.5973125 = idf(docFreq=3, maxDocs=146) 0.375 = fieldNorm(doc=126)
</str>
<str name="localhost/281/info/1373983754934/5ba362b4e8a6fce36ba650cf8e946771">
2.2986562 = (MATCH) weight(text_en:found in 131) [DefaultSimilarity], result of: 2.2986562 = fieldWeight in 131, product of: 1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of: 1.0 = termFreq=1.0 4.5973125 = idf(docFreq=3, maxDocs=146) 0.5 = fieldNorm(doc=131)
</str>
<str name="localhost/294/info/1373983755710/8a2e39f484dedff91bd11b94f442bd8a">
1.7239921 = (MATCH) weight(text_en:found in 136) [DefaultSimilarity], result of: 1.7239921 = fieldWeight in 136, product of: 1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of: 1.0 = termFreq=1.0 4.5973125 = idf(docFreq=3, maxDocs=146) 0.375 = fieldNorm(doc=136)
</str>
</lst>
</lst>
```

Even when I specified &sort=timestamp_tdt%20asc in the explain logs I see that it is calculating the turf , and product of scores etc.  Hope this helps to find an answer for your question.